# How to get specific version of code from git ?

Tags: git, asp.net-core-mvc

Actually I am quite new to git.

As I am learning ASP.net Core 1.0/1.1 but there is currently 2.0 preview in development.

I want to get 1.1.2 ( 1.1.2 ) MVC source  from git. Is there any possibility to do so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clone the repository

```
git clone --no-checkout https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc.git
```

and checkout the 1.1.2 tag

```
cd Mvc
git checkout rel/1.1.2
```

Answer (score 1):

If you clone the complete repository, you can see all the tags and branches, and then you can checkout to whichever branch or tag you desire.
In your case,

```
git clone https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc.git
git checkout rel/1.1.2
```

In case you are not bothered about other branches and tags, and just want the `rel/1.1.2` tag, you can directly clone with the `--branch` option.

```
git clone --depth=1 --branch rel/1.1.2 https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc.git
```

`--depth=1` is for getting the latest snapshot for the branch/tag specified. It won't fetch the complete history. You can ignore it in case you want to keep the history.